# Why isn't my form being submitted?

Tags: html, macos, forms, firefox, enctype

I've got a simple HTML form, thus:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input name="filesToUpload" id="filesToUpload" type="file" />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When the user clicks submit, I expect to see the result come back via the upload_file.php script. But on FF 4.01 on the mac, absolutely nothing happens. The URL in the address bar stays the same, and my php script doesn't get called on the server. I can get it to submit the form if I change the enctype to something other than "multipart/form-data", or if I change the method from "post".

I'm at a loss to work out what's going on. Is it a FF / Mac bug, or something schtoopid I'm doing.

FWIW, here's the PHP script. It's stolen almost verbatim from the [W3schools PHP upload tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp):

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["filesToUpload"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["filesToUpload"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["filesToUpload"]["name"] . "<br />";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["filesToUpload"]["type"] . "<br />";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["filesToUpload"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Can we see the upload script?

Comment: Probably the `upload_file.php` snippet will help explain. Also, have you tried other browsers?

Comment: Is the page refreshing, meaning a server request was made, or does it just do nothing?

Comment: No, the page doesn't refresh. Even if the php file doesn't exist I don't get an error from the server.

Comment: It seems to work with FF on PC, and Chrome on the mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, ok I seem to have worked it out. I had created a few dummy files to test the script I was going to use to check file name validity. But I created them just by going to the terminal and doing

```
touch testfile.txt testfile2.txt testfile3.txt
```

so the files were all zero bytes. This, it seems doesn't work for FF on the mac. It does for chrome however. On the PC I was choosing real files because I don't know the windows equivalent of the touch command, so that's why Firefox worked there.